# java.io.NotSerializableException with spring and @ViewScoped bean

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, jsf-2, migration

I do migration form JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.1 in a quite large project. There is a few libraries use: hibernate 3.6, spring 3.1(far as i know updated form 2.x by my predecessor), acegi-security-1.0.5, tomahawk20, urlrewrite-3.2.0. I will update all of them, when i finish migration to jsf2.1

I changed entries for beans in faces-config.xml to annotations, and change JSTL markup to JSF (c:if to rendered atribute or ui:fragment section) there is no JSTL now. Beans in this project had a lot of params. Ajax is used there, so I decided use @ViewScoped, but i have exception(pasted down). I don't know why with @SessionScoped exeption doesn't appear, and everything works correctly. I know SessionSoped life longer then View, but what is difference for this example?

I read a few Q&A hear and added Serializable interface to classes which i found in spring beans configuration files, but still doesn't work.

i.e for this entry:

```
<bean id="SomeDaoImpl" class="my.package">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I implemented Serializable in SomeDaoImpl class, but didn't help.

I added this entry to my web.xml, but still doesn't work.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

this class org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor i found in xml file where are spring beans,

EXCEPTION:

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/folder1/folder2/index.xhtml]
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor117.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:940)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1483)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(ObjectOutputStream.java:1346)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1154)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor117.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:940)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.doWriteState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:346)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ClientSideStateHelper.writeState(ClientSideStateHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:113)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:441)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
at org.apache.myfaces.tomahawk.application.ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ResourceViewHandlerWrapper.java:93)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at my.package.util.faces.LifecycleDecorator.render(LifecycleDecorator.java:90)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at my.package.util.ie9fix.ie9fixFilter.doFilter(ie9fixFilter.java:41)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:381)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:265)
at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:107)
at org.acegisecurity.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:72)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:166)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilter(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:125)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilter(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:135)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:81)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:271)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:249)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:275)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:149)
at org.acegisecurity.util.FilterToBeanProxy.doFilter(FilterToBeanProxy.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Any tips what should i check or read to understand what do i wrong?
I working with JSF for few weeks, and I am still learning. I never used spring.

Comment: Why do you have a `HibernateInterceptor` property in your JSF managed bean in first place?

Comment: @BalusC, I dont't understand. HibernateInterceptor is in spring bean, it is define in xml file by my predecessor.

Comment: You might want to look into CDI/EJB instead of legacy Spring. This problem doesn't exist in CDI/EJB as they use 100% proxies.

Comment: @BalusC I will look into CDI/EJB but I'm afraid it could be to hart for me now, I just start learning spring because of this project, and here is a lot of spring beans. Spring is responsible to communication with Database. And far as I know tomcat don't support EJB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're still getting the serialization exception because (as you can see from the stack trace) `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor` does not implement serializable. Somewhere in your view, there is use of an instance of this class and when JSF tries to serialize your viewstate to the client, it fails because of the offending class. 
Set your `STATE_SAVING_MODE` to `SERVER` in your web.xml by adding the following entry to your web.xml

```
   <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>SERVER</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

If you must have it the other way (`CLIENT`), you need to mark the variable referring to the offending class as `transient` so that it's ignored during serialization

Comment: Exception disappear, but now with ViewScoped i change input data in form, but calculation are done for default input in my form, nothing change in result. With SessionScope it works correctly. I changed javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING to true.

Comment: @k.nieszporek wait, with `javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING = true`, your view fails?

Comment: yes, it is, i have
   <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
but @ViewScoped doesn't work. With SessionScoped it works.

Comment: I found [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers) it should be javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING = false, but still doesn't work;/

Comment: javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD = SERVER, it solved exception, but @ViewScoped doesn't work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13085749/viewscoped-doesnt-work-bean-is-created-for-every-request